# How to save data with pwa

Tags: javascript, progressive-web-apps

I am working on my own project where I want to create an application, which runs on android and iOS. I decide using HTML, CSS and JavaScript for creating a PWA. The app should enable the user to manage recips for tart incl. Cost calculation. My problem is, that I want to save the recips/ingredients in form of a table. The data should be stored permanently locally on the device. With the method "localstorage" the data are only saved temporarily. I don't want to host a webserver/database. The data should not be lost when the user delete the local cache of the browser.
Is it possible to store general data with java script, for example in a text file, outside of the browser's cache?

Comment: In your case [indexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) would be my go to solution.

Comment: look for a "serverless" database like firestore or parse

Answer (score 2):

In your case [indexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IndexedDB_API) would be my go to solution. It can be deleted by a user as all data stored in the browser. Browser can't store data in text files (at least as per October 2021)

Comment: indexedDB is risky: I lost many photos stored into it with my PWA: now I'm looking for a more persistent way to store data.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible. but it's not straightforward it must be done manually by the user.
You can generate your DB as a downloadable file -eg. `.txt` or `.csv`- and provide the download link for the user or just auto-download it.
here's an example.

```
function download(filename, text) {
  var element = document.createElement('a');
  element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(text));
  element.setAttribute('download', filename);

  element.style.display = 'none';
  document.body.appendChild(element);

  element.click();

  document.body.removeChild(element);
}

// Start file download.
document.getElementById("dwn-btn").addEventListener("click", function(){
// Start the download of yournewfile.txt file with the content from the text area
    var text = document.getElementById("text-val").value;
    var filename = "yournewfile.txt";
    
    download(filename, text);
}, false);
```

to load the data you can create an import button that receives the data and populates the table.
here's how you can read file data

```
function readImage(file) {
  // Check if the file is text.
  if (file.type && !file.type.startsWith('text/')) {
    console.log('File is not an textfile.', file.type, file);
    return;
  }

  const reader = new FileReader();
  reader.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
    img.src = event.target.result;
  });
  reader.readAsDataURL(file);
}
```

I recommend using this approach with indexedDb or local storage.